# Who are the people who others forget when there is sufficient distance between them?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, episode-identification

I seem to remember an episode where a woman appeared on the bridge asking for help as if she knew the crew and was in love with one of them. (Riker? Chakotay?) However this race is forgotten by outsiders when they are a distance away from them.

The Star Trek ship has just spent considerable time getting to know these people but after parting (and our heroes forgetting, including computers records, which also faded) the lady love left her people to run back to the Federation ship (forbidden by her people). Her people were chasing her, demanding her return, but she didn't want to go. She ended up going back and because of the memory thing, her love interest hand wrote a journal entry about her so that he would not forget.

**Who are these people, which series was it and what episode?**

Comment: this was a voyager episode, but I can't recall which one. Chakotay keeps a written record because anything electronic will be wiped.

Comment: I think I know who you are talking about... but I forgot.   (sorry, hard to pass up!)

Comment: Could have just skimmed through a list of episode synopses?

Answer (score 27):

### This is the Voyager episode [Unforgettable](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unforgettable_(episode))

> Chakotay meets a woman who claims that they fell in love a few weeks
>   before, although he doesn't remember her anymore.

The woman's name is [Kellin](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kellin_(Ramuran)) and her species is called the [Ramurans](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ramuran).

Comment: Thank you so much. At first I was thinking it was next gen and Riker - after all, he does get the girls. Then when I couldn't find it I thought maybe it was a time when the enterprise visited DS9, but that didn't make sense. It was only recently that I thought maybe it was Chakotay. I asked friends and they all thought I was hallucinating. I have to go watch it now. Thank you again!!